# Select row value from column in interactive report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle18c

Version: Oracle 18.2

I have an interactive report in my application. When I click the 'delete' icon, I want to delete information about the user I selected. Is there a way to get the value from the 'Facility Manager' column so I can use that value in a select statement to perform the delete statement.

I've tried to do it by using the ROW_ID variable (:selected_rowid) but this didn't work.

**+ Interactive Report Image**

[image: Interactive Report Image]

**+ Set Value statement**

[image: Set Value statement]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column value is referenced by hashes, e.g. `#STUDENT_ID#`.

Have a look at what Jackie McIlroy wrote, "**Delete a Row of a Report with a Dynamic Action**" (https://jackiemcilroy.blogspot.com/2018/03/delete-row-of-report-with-dynamic-action.html) . She describes the process in details, with a lot of screenshots.

---

If I were you, I'd do one of the following:

- use an interactive report with a form (and navigate to the form in order to delete a row)
- if it has to be a tabular layout, I'd try

  - the *old* tabular form
  - the *new* interactive grid

I don't think I'd remove rows from the interactive report (but OK, that's just me, and my ideas usually aren't too smart).